# How can I add a url redirect to this jQuery Countdown

Tags: jquery, url, redirect, countdown

I need to add a url redirect to this coding

this is the jquery code
 I need it to redirect when the countdown gets to zero

```
$(function(){
    $('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
        targetDate: {
            'day':   27,
            'month': 1,
            'year':  2012,
            'hour':  0,
            'min':   0,
            'sec':   0
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: What is *countDown*? A plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(function(){
 $('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
  targetDate: {
         'day':     27,
         'month':   1,
         'year':    2012,
         'hour':    0,
         'min':     0,
         'sec':     0
            },
   onComplete: function() { window.location.href = 'some URL'; }   
   });
 });
```

http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/example.php?e=on_complete